# Variables values are not showing in eclipse debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug code in eclipse, I don't see values of variables in joda Interval.class when I hover on the variables.

I do see the the values of other variables defined in other .class files (not joda classes).

It is just for the joda classes. I did reset debug perspective and deleted target folder and created it agin, but the issue still exists. Please check the attachment.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[image: variabled_values_not_showing_up]

Answer (score 1):

```
My problem are solved changing maven pom.xml file...
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```